# Security difference jquery form submit vs ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

Is there an actual difference between the options:

- Form submit (POST) using jQuery;
- Ajax POST using jQuery;

From a **security** point of view?
Note: we want to make a REStful POST.

Comment: Potato/Potato  ...I feel like the meaning of that is somewhat lost when I type that out. I'm just saying those are the same thing.

Comment: I understand, my point is that the only way to submit a form using jQuery is with AJAX, so the two options you listed are the same thing. If you mean making a standard (non-AJAX) form POST versus an AJAX POST, there is no difference in security as they too are nearly identical processes.

Comment: @RobM. Thanks. That's what I thought, but I guess that one cannot be too sure. With jQuery post, I meant indd triggering the default form submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both perform the same HTTP request in this scenario.  So they are both on the same level of security.

I'm guessing your concern should be focused on how that data is protected.  Like having your application and/or API based on the HTTPS protocol and protecting against XSS attacks so data can't be leaked from the client.

The major differences the two would pose in a non-security aspect is user-friendliness.  Ajax can be performed in the background and a form request cannot.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.